# Как передать функции n-е число значений строкой , а не кортежом строк?)

Tags: python

Помогите решить задачу , аргумент num_jek должен принимать одно строковое значение а аргумент my_num n-ное количество строковых значений!!)

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'


def number(num_jek: str, *my_num: str):
    '''Функция принимает два строчных аргумента'''
    '''Один аргумент сравниваеться с другим аргументом'''
    '''Если есть совпадение то оно добовляеться в список'''


    num_list = num_jek.split(' ') # Аргументы с функции преобразуються в список
    num_my_list = my_num.split(' ') # Таким оброзом строка написаная через пробел становиться новым обьектом списка
    num_res = [] # Список свереных результатов

    for number in num_list: # Цикл фор сравнивает два аргумента если ,
        if number in num_my_list: # в num_jek есть значение с my_num то значение добовляеться в num_res.
            num_res.append(number)
    num_str = ','.join(num_res) # Список num_res преобразуеться в строку.
    return num_str


a = (number('1 2 3 4 5 6', '1 2 3 4 5 6', '1 2 3 4 5 6', '1 2 3 4 5 6', '1 2 3 4 5 6'))

print(a)
```

Comment: Дык у Вас `my_num` внутри функции это кортеж строк, а не строка. Вы пытаетесь применить метод `split` у кортежа, о чём ошибка и говорит.

Comment: не правильно вопрос задал , как передать n-ое количество строк ? а не кортеж строк?

Comment: @UserName дак исправьте это там, а не в комментариях пишите.

Comment: @UserName Как Вы понимаете `n-ое количество строк`? Вообще не очевидная вещь.

Comment: @UserName возможно n-e количество аргументов?

Comment: Надо было немного подумать а было в лом , решил задачу так)

    num_tuple = [str(item) for sub in my_num for item in sub]
    num_my = ' '.join(num_tuple )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вы написали в вопросе `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'`
Означает то, что на tuple объект нельзя вызвать метод split, а переменное число параметров(аргументов) 
`*my_num` возвращает как раз tuple.

Теперь перейдём к заданию. как я понял вам нужно находить одинаковые значения в аргументах и выводить их в виде строки.

В вашем коде `num_my_list = my_num.split(' ')` список составлен неправильно, поэтому интерпретатор ругается)

Цикл, который делает у вас всю работу не проверял.

В своём коде я немного по-иному находил одинаковые значения. Так же я заменил название переменных на более короткие, чтоб легче было читать. как и у вас код с tupe hint'ами `(num_jek: str, *my_num: str)` . Активно использовал list comprehansion ,  что позволило уместить весь код во всего 10 строк чистого кода.

Наконец решение:

```
def get_equal(x: str, *y: str):

    l1 = x.split(' ')

    cur_list = [i.split(' ') for i in list(y)]
    l2 = []
    for lst in cur_list:
        l2 += lst

    #print('{}\n{}'.format(l1, l2)) # уберите знак комментария, чтобы вывести на консоль 2 списка.

    identic = [i for i in l1 for _ in l2 if i == _] # Назвал переменную _ так, потому что её имя не играет роли. 

    result = ', '.join(identic)

    return(result)

print(get_equal('11 2 378 44', '5 8 9 6 6 44', '55 77 6 1 4 8', '378 5 2 748'))
```

Вот вывод:

```
$ python stack.py
2, 378, 44
```